# Asigning a rank (lowest value to highest) to a numeric value in one column based on an identifier in another column

Tags: r

I would need help asigning a rank (lowest value to highest) to some numeric values in one column. The values that should be included in this have an identifier in a different column (Here Significant = Yes).

I want to add a new column where I rank numeric values by their fold change ("log2FC") with the identifier *Significant=Yes* in the *Significant* column.

I would appreciate the help.

#initial data

```r
treatment=c(100,200,100,400)
cotrol=c(100,100,400,100)
log2FC=c(0,1,-2,2)
Significance=c(No,Yes,Yes,Yes)
data=data.frame(treatment,cotrol,log2FC,Significance)
```

| treatment | cotrol | log2FC | Significance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | 0 | No |
| 200 | 100 | 1 | Yes |
| 100 | 400 | -2 | Yes |
| 400 | 100 | 2 | Yes |

| treatment | cotrol | log2FC | Significance | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | 0 | No |  |
| 200 | 100 | 1 | Yes | 2 |
| 100 | 400 | -2 | Yes | 1 |
| 400 | 100 | 2 | Yes | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rank` on the subset of rows:

```r
data$Rank[data$Significance == "Yes"] <- rank(data$log2FC[data$Significance == "Yes"])
```

output

```r
  treatment cotrol log2FC Significance Rank
1       100    100      0           No   NA
2       200    100      1          Yes    2
3       100    400     -2          Yes    1
4       400    100      2          Yes    3
```